# Relation between Dirichlet convolution and Bell series and convolution of functions and the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, convolution, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-convolution

We define the Dirichlet convolution of two arithmetic functions $a,b:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ to be
$$
(a*b)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}a(d)b\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).
$$
Given a prime $p$, we define the Bell series of $a$ to be
$$
a_p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(p^n)x^n.
$$
Both of these definitions are taken from Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. It is easy to show that if $c=a*b$, then $c_p(x)=a_p(x)b_p(x)$ for all primes $p$.

There are some pretty obvious cosmetic similarities here between the definition of Dirichlet convolution and this result with Bell series and the usual notion of convolution in analysis and how the Fourier transform interacts with it ($\widehat{f*g}=\hat{f}\cdot\hat{g}$). Are these similarities actually significant?

More specifically, can Dirichlet convolution be viewed somehow as the usual convolution of two functions on some group with a measure? Are Bell series related in any way to Fourier transforms or Fourier coefficients, or is it just nice and convenient to have results about different types of products interacting well with each other?

Comment: The underlying structure you're noticing is not coincidental. Look into 'abstract harmonic analysis' -- many properties of the Fourier transform hold on any sufficiently nice abstract group.

Comment: @Potato I know a little bit of abstract harmonic analysis. When you said "sufficiently nice abstract group", did you mean a locally compact Hausdorff group or something else?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: This phenomenon also holds for Dirichlet series, another tool frequently used in multiplicative number theory